# org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource User.hbm.xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, maven

As an output I m receiving error:

> org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource User.hbm.xml.

I have tried solving it using links:

[Could not parse mapping document from resource Books.hbm.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35308512/could-not-parse-mapping-document-from-resource-books-hbm-xml)

[Hibernate and maven: Could not parse mapping document from resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513403/hibernate-and-maven-could-not-parse-mapping-document-from-resource)

I'm trying to enter values in database using pojo class

User.hbm.xml

```
               <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.program.User" table="user">
        <id name="ID" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="NAME" type="java.lang.String" column="name">
            <column name="name" />
        </property>
        <property name="AGE" type="int" column="age">
            <column name="age" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Program.java

```
            package com.program;

            import org.hibernate.Session;
            import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
            import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

            public class Program {

                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    try{
                        System.out.println("hello world");
                        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();;
                        Session session = factory.openSession();
                        session.beginTransaction();
                        User user = new User();
                        user.setID(1);
                        user.setNAME("Toral");
                        user.setAGE(21);
                        session.save(user);
                        session.getTransaction().commit();
                        session.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                }

            }
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
        <hibernate-configuration>
            <session-factory>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student</property>
                <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
                <property name="show_sql">true</property>
                <property name="format_sql">true</property>
                <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update </property>
                <mapping resource="User.hbm.xml" />
            </session-factory>
        </hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Can you paste the file structure of where `user.hbm.xml` is placed?

Comment: <property name="NAME" type="java.lang.String" column="name">
            <column name="name" />
        </property>

Comment: You might need to change hibernate-mapping tab to include the package as such:
<hibernate-mapping package="your.package.here">
depending on your file structure.

Comment: problem solved. 2 times column name specified

Comment: Post the structure as well as the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misplaced actual value for "name" attribute ane "column" attribute.

"name" attribute represents property of your POJO class.

"column" attribute represents column name of your table.

Try this:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.program.User" table="user">
    <id name="id" type="int" column="ID">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="java.lang.String" column="NAME"></property>
    <property name="age" type="int" column="AGE"></property>
</class>
```